# Express $\tan\alpha-i$ in the form $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification

> Express $\tan\alpha-i$ in the form $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

**My Attempt:**

$\frac{\sin\alpha-i\cos\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\sec\alpha(\cos(\frac{3\pi}2+\alpha)+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}2+\alpha))$

**Is my answer incomplete?**

The answer given in the book is

$\sec\alpha(\cos(\alpha-\frac{\pi}2)+i\sin(\alpha-\frac{\pi}2)), 0\le\alpha\lt\frac\pi2$

And,

$-\sec\alpha(\cos(\frac{\pi}2+\alpha)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}2+\alpha)), \frac\pi2\lt\alpha\le\pi$

Is the answer given in book better? Also, why have they considered only first and second quadrants and not third and fourth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the last question first, the tangent function has period $\pi,$ and is undefined at odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}.$ Thus, in order to specify the behavior of $\tan\alpha-i,$ it suffices to do so for only two quadrants. I generally prefer to do so for all $\alpha$ in the interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$ Strangely, the book decided to do so for the two intervals $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right],$ instead. This is a bit odd, because once it has been stated what happens for $\alpha=0,$ periodicity already tells you what happens for $\alpha=\pi.$

---

Now let's see if one of them is better than the other.

The secant function has period $2\pi,$ and is undefined at odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}.$ Consequently, both your formula and the book's formulas are undefined when $\alpha$ is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2},$ just like $\tan\alpha-i$ is. Looking good so far!

The cosine and sine functions have a period of $2\pi$. Since $\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha,$ then $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)=\cos\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)=\sin\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$ Thus, for $0\leq\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2},$ your formula is equal to the book's formula.

Another property of the sine and cosine functions is that a shift of $\pi$ in either direction negates them--that is, for example, $\sin(\theta+\pi)=-\sin(\theta).$ Since $\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha+\pi=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha,$ then $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)=-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha\right).$ Thus, once again, for $\frac{\pi}{2}<\alpha\leq\pi,$ your formula is equal to the book's formula.

---

So why did the book make two different formulas, if your one formula is equal to their formulas? Well, the kicker about the form $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ is that $r$ must be **non-negative**. That's why the book split things up piecewise, and why your answer is not quite right.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome!